# Changing window title font style and color

Tags: gtk

How can I change window title font style and font color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The titlebar text is managed by your operating system's [window manager](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Window_manager), and the only thing you can do as an application programmer is change the text value.

That is, unless you want to draw your own (fake) title bar. That's generally frowned upon, though. If you really want to, you can take a look at the source code of apps that do this, for example Chromium.